# QGIS 2.18.7: How can I change or add WMS parameters?

Tags: qgis, wms, parameters

I'm trying to add open data from MétéoFrance (French meteorological organisation) as WMS with QGIS 2.18.7 on Windows 7.

The URL looks like this, I've added it to my WMS connections (with my valid token):

```
https://geoservices.meteofrance.fr/api/TOKEN/ClimNormalesWMORes40EssMetroWMS?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=41.21598999999999791,-5.14082300000000014,51.48935699999999827,8.38489399999999918&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=515&HEIGHT=392&LAYERS=JANUARY_NORMALS_OF_MEAN_PRESSURE_REDUCED_TO_MSL&STYLES=DejaVuSans_circle_orange&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE
```

But if I add the layer to my empty project, nothing loads. The layer is in my list, but it doesn't show anything.
The support told me, that there is always `styles=DejaVuSans_circle_orange` or format `image%2Fpng` (`%2F` replaces `/`) missing in my request.

The layer source is indicated as

```
contextualWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:4326&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=JANUARY_NORMALS_OF_MEAN_PRESSURE_REDUCED_TO_MSL&styles=DejaVuSans_circle_orange&url=https://geoservices.meteofrance.fr/api/TOKEN/ClimNormalesWMORes40EssMetroWMS?VERSION%3D1.3.0%26BBOX%3D41.21598999999999791,-5.14082300000000014,51.48935699999999827,8.38489399999999918%26CRS%3DEPSG:4326%26WIDTH%3D515%26HEIGHT%3D392%26LAYERS%3DJANUARY_NORMALS_OF_MEAN_PRESSURE_REDUCED_TO_MSL%26STYLES%3DDejaVuSans_circle_orange%26DPI%3D96%26MAP_RESOLUTION%3D96%26FORMAT_OPTIONS%3Ddpi:96%26TRANSPARENT%3DTRUE
```

Another possible URL structure is:

```
https://geoservices.meteofrance.fr/services/ClimNormalesWMORes40EssMetroWMS?version=1.3.0&token=TOKEN&BBOX=41.21598999999999791,-5.14082300000000014,51.48935699999999827,8.38489399999999918&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=515&HEIGHT=392&LAYERS=JANUARY_NORMALS_OF_MEAN_TEMPERATURE&STYLES=DejaVuSans_circle_noir&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE
```

But the structure above is the one that their service gave me.

In my browser a png appears, it seems to be the right data.

Even if I choose png and the DejaVuSans_circle_orange layer from the connection list, it doesn't work.

How can I add this parameters to my request? Or is there another way to load the WMS in QGIS?

Comment: What result do you get if you open the request in a browser

Comment: Is it really `api/TOKEN` in the URL?  The following document https://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr/client/gfx/utilisateur/File/documentation-webservices-inspire-en.pdf has a different URL structure

Comment: That's right, they have two different URL structures. With: https://geoservices.meteofrance.fr/services/ClimNormalesWMORes40EssMetroWMS?version=1.3.0&token=TOKEN&BBOX=41.21598999999999791,-5.14082300000000014,51.48935699999999827,8.38489399999999918&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=515&HEIGHT=392&LAYERS=JANUARY_NORMALS_OF_MEAN_TEMPERATURE&STYLES=DejaVuSans_circle_noir&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE I get the same (no) result.

Comment: In my browser a png appears. (It's not what I expected, but it seem to be the right thing.)

Comment: The generated GetMap request looks correct, but to check that there is no other issue, it always good to run the request in the browser rather than through some client such as QGIS

Comment: Can you add those details to the question.  The GetMap request is for a png, so what is it about the png that isn't as expected

Comment: I simply expected the data being continuous, not for some stations. But I has nothing to do with my request being right or wrong. In the browser it is right and works.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you were expecting.  Please edit the question to add more details,

Comment: Forget about the part what I was expecting, it was about the data itself, not the way of getting it as a WMS in QGIS. I don't know which details to add... I want to get this wms in QGIS with the parameters above - in my browser it loads, in QGIS the content doesn't load...

Answer (score 1):

When I add the following WMS to QGIS, from the same supplier, I get a map and a legend ([https://geoservices.meteofrance.fr/api/**my-token**/MF-NWP-GLOBAL-ARPEGE-05-GLOBE-WMS](https://geoservices.meteofrance.fr/api/__my-token__/MF-NWP-GLOBAL-ARPEGE-05-GLOBE-WMS)?)

For example, I can load the following layer `PRESSURE__MEAN_SEA_LEVEL`

When I look at the GetCapabilities response for this service/layer I can see:

```
<Style>
 <Name>P__SEA__NO_SHADING</Name>
 <Title>Style de représentation d'un champ de pression réduite au niveau de la mer, avec isolignes sans remplissage</Title>
 <LegendURL>
  <Format>image/png</Format>
  <OnlineResource xlink:href="https://geoservices.meteofrance.fr/api/__my-token__/MF-NWP-GLOBAL-ARPEGE-05-GLOBE-WMS?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&sld_version=1.1.0&request=GetLegendGraphic&layer=PRESSURE__MEAN_SEA_LEVEL&style=P__SEA__NO_SHADING&format=image/png"/>
 </LegendURL>
</Style>
```

Now, when I look at the service in your question ([https://geoservices.meteofrance.fr/api/**my-token**/ClimNormalesWMORes40EssMetroWMS](https://geoservices.meteofrance.fr/api/__my-token__/ClimNormalesWMORes40EssMetroWMS)?), I can't get any style variant to provide a map in QGIS, for the `JANUARY_NORMALS_OF_MEAN_PRESSURE_REDUCED_TO_MSL` layer and I get no legend.

When I look at the GetCapabilities response for this service/layer I can see:

```
<Style>
 <Name>DejaVuSans_circle_orange</Name>
 <Title>Valeur numérique et position station (point orange) </Title>
</Style>
<Style>
 <Name>Synopsis</Name>
 <Title>Valeur numérique uniquement</Title>
</Style>
<Style>
 <Name>DejaVuSans_circle_noir</Name>
 <Title>Valeur numérique et position station (point noir)</Title>
</Style>
```

In other words there is no LegendURL and that certainly means that QGIS can't create a legend for the TOC.

I suspect that this is also the reason why no map gets drawn, for example when I add a new layer from a WMS service I see, in order, QGIS making three requests (after I select the layer in the Add WMS Layer dialogue):

1. GetCapabilities
2. GetLegendGraphic
3. GetMap

My thinking here is, if the GetLegendGraphic operation/URL doesn't exist, perhaps QGIS stops making requests and the GetMap operation doesn't get called...

Looking at the *[Styled Layer Descriptor profile of the Web Map Service Implementation Specification](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=22364)* I see that GetLegendGraphic is an optional operation for an SLD enabled WMS, so it appears that the service provider is not in error for not supporting such an operation.

It might be worth flagging this as a QGIS bug.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So do I get it right, that the missing GetLegendGraphic is a "mistake" done by the supplier? Or can I change my request so as to get the request that I need?

Comment: I don't think you can change your request.  Both QGIS and the supplier may be at fault.  You'll need to check the SLD specification to see who is correct.  You might be able to work around the issue by cascading the WMS through your​ own copy of MapServer or GeoServer...